# how do I get the section title, sub_section_title and file in the formData in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am developing an application using laravel 8 and vuejs. I am trying to post form data from my vuejs to backend(laravel) but it is not working

The vuejs creates a subsection of a section which is add to an array of subsection inside the section array which is converted to string and added to a form data then sent as a request to my backend.

The frontend is working perfectly well but I cant access the data on my backend. How do I get the values of the course title, section title, sub section title and file added

Vuejs

```
<script>
import { reactive } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";


export default {
  name: 'CreateCourse',
  setup(){
      const sections = reactive([{'section_title': '', 'sub_sections': [{'sub_section_title': '', 'file': '', 'url': ''}]}]);
      const course = reactive({'title': '', 'description': ''});

    const addSection = () => {
        sections.push({"section_title": "", 'sub_sections': [{'sub_section_title': '', 'file': '', 'url': ''}]});
    }
    const addSubSection = (idx) => {
        console.log('the value of idx is ', idx);
        sections[idx].sub_sections.push({"sub_section_title": "", 'file': '', 'url': ''});
    }

    const uploadFile = (e, idx, i) => {
        sections[idx].sub_sections[i].file = e.target.files[0];
        sections[idx].sub_sections[i].url = URL.createObjectURL(sections[idx].sub_sections[i].file);
    }

    const createCourse = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
   
    let newCourse = JSON.stringify(course)
    let newSection = JSON.stringify(sections)

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("course", newCourse);
    formData.append("sections", newSection);
    showLoader(true);
    axios.post('/api', form, { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}}).then(response =>                  
        {
        NotificationService.success(response.data.message);
        showLoader(false);
        course.title = '';
        course.description = '';
    }).catch(err => {
        NotificationService.error(err.response);
        showLoader(false);
    });
  }
  return {
    course,
    createCourse,
    sections,
    addSection,
    addSubSection,
    uploadFile
  }
}
</script>
```

laravel code

```
            echo $request->get("title");
            echo $request->get("description");
           
            foreach($request->section_title as $titles)    
            {


               echo $titles                    
            }

                foreach($request->section_sub_title as $sub_titles)
                {
                    // info($sub_titles);
                    // return $sub_titles;
                    
                   echo $sub_titles
                    
                }


{"course":{"title":"Frontend","description":"This is building web interface with html, css and javascript"},"sections":[{"section_title":"HTML","sub_sections":[{"sub_section_title":"What is HTML","file":{},"url":"blob:http://localhost:8080/ea0acc7d-34e6-4bff-9255-67794acd8fab"}]}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit tricky to understand where you're stuck, but let's give it a shot:

1. Does the api request actually reach your route (post -> `/api`), do you see in the network tab a post request to the route?
2. Have you tried running `dd($request->all())` in the controller method so see what you're getting (just do this on the first line inside your method)?

**Small gotcha moment:**
Sometimes it helps to run `the php artisan route:clear`command

Comment: Thanks for you response. I have update my question with the reponse